# Have I really put on 14 lbs after only 4 Crossfit sessions?

Tags: weight-gain, bodyweight, crossfit

I'm a skinny, unfit 24-year-old male weighing 143.3 pounds (65 kg). I started Crossfit two weeks ago (along with a healthy, fruit and protein-rich diet) on the basis of 2 workouts per week. 
Today, I had my 4th workout (2nd week) and went to buy a scale. When I came home, I weighed myself naked before having anything to eat to see if I had put on any weight yet. Turns out I now weigh 157.8 pounds (71.6 kg).
Is this normal? Is my scale wrong? Is this too much in too little time to be true?

Comment: How sure are you that the first weighing was accurate?

Comment: Well, I'm only sure to the extent that I trust all the former scales I have been using for the past year to weigh myself. Now, I'm just worried I was wrong and haven't kept track properly.

Comment: Eh, if it wasn't done under the same conditions (i.e. when you first get up, clothing, etc), I wouldn't be too startled. Digital scales have error rates,  but are generally consistent to themselves. Also, weight can fluctuate quite a few pounds in a day, and you may also be retaining water due to new training. Just keep weighing under the same conditions each day going forward, and use this as the baseline.

Comment: So, if someone asks me how much I weigh, do I keep saying 65kg, or can I now consider I weigh 71kg?

Comment: I'd go with the most current. But, I'd also advise against chasing a mythical weight. Use the scale to track trends, but gauge progress by the mirror. I really don't care about my weight, other than to stay within a range and have the strength to do the sports I do.

Comment: My scale changes up and down 5kg just from where it stands on the tiles. These things are just useless.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much been addressed in the comments, but for a full answer:

Short answer, no. You most likely did not gain that much weight in a short period of time.

Things that can effect scale measurements without any changes to body composition:

1. The scales themselves.

   - Most home scales tend to be fairly inaccurate.
   - You can step off one scale, move to another and it will have a
     completely different reading.
   - You mentioned you bought a new scale. It is in all likelihood that it will be off a few lbs./kgs. compared to your old one.
   - However, the inaccuracy of a single scale is consistent. So if you use the same scale moving forward, you can use it to track changes over time. Just average the numbers over the week and you should see a gradual increase.
2. The placement of the scale.

   - Scales generally have four feet that should be placed firmly on the floor.
   - You need to make sure none of the feet are in any cracks of tiles.
   - Make sure there is nothing under the scale that could be holding up the plate of the scale.
   - Don't ever put a scale on a soft surface like carpet or rugs. It will negate absolutely everything.
3. Feet placement on the scale and how you stand on it.

   - The value of the scale can vary depending on where you stand on it.
   - Try to avoid leaning on any direction.

Although, it may be possible that you gained *some* weight in that time.  Dramatic increases in body weight is common when people just start working out.

1. Increased food intake.

   - There's just physically more stuff in your body so you're going to have a *slight* increase in body weight.
2. Water retention.

   - Increased carbohydrates will cause the body to hold more water.
   - Supplements such as creatine will cause water retention.
   - Increased salt intake either purposefully or as a side effect of increased eating will cause a lot of water retention.
   - Working out can cause a slight increase in water retention.

Though it wouldn't be that dramatic. Most of the weight difference sounds like it is from scale mishaps.